# how to validate files before uploading in angular 6

Tags: validation, file-upload, angular6, mime-types

How can I `validate` files before uploading in angular 4 and above?
i want `file type` and `file size` validation in angular 4 and above.
[Screenshot of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPIC3.png)

for each and every file I am getting correct file size and type except **.msg** file. How to get 
file type as **application/vnd.ms-outlook
application/octet-stream**
 for **outlook** files. Please help me out.

Comment: This is not the way to ask a question. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You have given no context as to what you are doing. What you have done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is a bit (lot) vague. I assume you mean, how do you get the `File` object from an input in Angular. Dead simple. The same way you would with vanilla(ish) JS.

In your component, create a function to read your file:

```
readFile(fileEvent: any) {
   const file = fileEvent.target.files[0];
   console.log('size', file.size);
   console.log('type', file.type);
}
```

And apply it to the `(change)` event on your input in your template:

```
<input type="file" (change)="readFile($event)">
```

You can do whatever you like with the file after that. The sample function just gets the size and type, as per your question.

Stackblitz Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpvotz

As a (slight) aside, rather than using `any` as the `fileEvent` type, you can define an interface to give you type hinting.

```
interface HTMLInputEvent extends Event {
    target: HTMLInputElement & EventTarget;
}
```

While you're at it, also add the `File` type too. So your function becomes:

```
readFile(fileEvent: HTMLInputEvent) {
   const file: File = fileEvent.target.files[0];
   console.log('size', file.size);
   console.log('type', file.type);
}
```

But, you don't have to. Although `any` types are not recommended.

Comment: How to check .msg files(outlook) file type? while checking, I am getting empty string.

Comment: Assuming you have your file read in correctly, you should be checking `file.type` for a type of `application/vnd.ms-outlook`.... failing that, check the extension on the filename... e.g `isEmail(file: File) { return file.name.substring(file.name.length - 4, file.name.length) === '.msg';`